# Assume that each user attempts to use a specific timeslot with probability p. If there are n users, what is the probability of a collision?

Tags: statistics

> Consider a random access communication channel. When more than one user (2 or more) attempts to use the channel during a given timeslot, a collision occurs. Assume that each user attempts to use a specific timeslot (independent of other users) with probability $p$. If there are $n$ users, what is the probability of a collision?

Not exactly sure how to approach this problem. So I need $P($2 or more users$)$ attempt to access the same channel. I believe this is a Bernoulli probability, meaning $k\geq 2$.

Any tips?

Comment: Hint: What is the probability that nobody uses the channel? What is the probability that exactly one user does?

Comment: I believe the probability that nobody uses the channel is the compliment. 1-p.

Comment: Independently of the number of users? Seems unlikely, no?